# how to read variable lines from two txt files in perl and write them in to another txt file

Tags: perl

I want to automate the following Perl code. So that it will read variable number of lines from  two txt files and write these lines in to another txt file.

I have two txt files (`1st_file.txt`) and (`2nd_file.txt`) and I want to read variable no. of lines from these files. How can I do that? The Perl code given below does the same job but if I change the txt files I also need to change my Perl code, which is not very efficient.

So can anybody guide me about how to write an efficient Perl code for the problem given below?
So if I change the data in my txt files I will get my desired results but without changing the Perl code.

What does change mean here? It means that let say if I remove line 5 to 7 from 1st_file.txt which are `207 --> A_207_P2_M2A  --> T_207_P2_M2A` and I also remove line 4 from 2nd_file.txt which is `P2_M2A`. So right now after removing these lines I want to make change in my Perl code too to get the desired results, because I removed these lines. But I want a Perl code in which I do not need to make any modifications if I make some changes in both of the txt files accordingly.

**Perl Code:**

```
use warnings;
use strict;

open (FILE1, 'g:\perl_tests\1st_file.txt');
open (FILE2, 'g:\perl_tests\2nd_file.txt');
open (FILE3, '> g:\perl_tests\3rd_file.txt');

my @speech1 = <FILE1>;
my @speech2 = <FILE2>;

print FILE3 @speech2[0..1];
print FILE3 @speech1[1..2];
print FILE3 @speech1[5..6];
print FILE3 @speech2[4..6];
print FILE3 @speech1[9..10];
print FILE3 @speech2[8..10];
print FILE3 @speech1[13..14];
print FILE3 @speech2[12..14];
print FILE3 @speech1[17..18];
print FILE3 @speech2[16..18];
print FILE3 @speech1[21..22];
print FILE3 @speech1[25..26];
print FILE3 @speech1[29..30];
```

**1st_file.txt**

```
153
A_153_P1_M2A_Some text is written here
T_153_P1_M2A_Some text is written here

207
A_207_P2_M2A_Some text is written here
T_207_P2_M2A_Some text is written here

48
A_48_P1_T1B_Some text is written here
T_48_P1_T1B_Some text is written here

57
A_57_P1_T2A_Some text is written here
T_57_P1_T2A_Some text is written here

167
A_167_P1_W1C_Some text is written here
T_167_P1_W1C_Some text is written here

26
A_26_P1_W2B_Some text is written here
T_26_P1_W2B_Some text is written here

183
A_183_P2_W2B_Some text is written here
T_183_P2_W2B_Some text is written here

69
A_69_P3_W2B_Some text is written here
T_69_P3_W2B_Some text is written here
```

**2nd_file.txt**

```
M2A
Top_M2A
P1_M2A
P2_M2A

T1B
Top_T1B
P1_T1B

T2A
Top_T2A
P1_T2A

W1C
Top_W1C
P1_W1C

W2B
Top_W2B
P1_W2B
P2_W2B
P3_W2B
```

**3rd_file.txt (Output: which is generated by Perl code, should be the one which is given below)**

```
M2A
Top_M2A
A_153_P1_M2A_Some text is written here
T_153_P1_M2A_Some text is written here
A_207_P2_M2A_Some text is written here
T_207_P2_M2A_Some text is written here

T1B
Top_T1B
A_48_P1_T1B_Some text is written here
T_48_P1_T1B_Some text is written here

T2A
Top_T2A
A_57_P1_T2A_Some text is written here
T_57_P1_T2A_Some text is written here

W1C
Top_W1C
A_167_P1_W1C_Some text is written here
T_167_P1_W1C_Some text is written here

W2B
Top_W2B
A_26_P1_W2B_Some text is written here
T_26_P1_W2B_Some text is written here
A_183_P2_W2B_Some text is written here
T_183_P2_W2B_Some text is written here
A_69_P3_W2B_Some text is written here
T_69_P3_W2B_Some text is written here
```

Can any one guide me in solving this issue.

Comment: Based on what criteria you select which rows are printed and when? Without such rule you can't make what you want.

Comment: You need to be checking the return code from `open`.  If for some reason one of your `open` calls fails, you won't know it.  Do it like this: `open (FILE1, 'g:\perl_tests\1st_file.txt') or die $!`, because `$!` is the error message variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are grouping the lines by the last part after the underscore. It is a bit unclear in what order the lines should be printed (e.g. if `P1_M2A` came after `P2_M2A` in the 2nd file), but the following code gives exactly the expected output for the data you gave.

It first reads the 1st_file into a hash, remembering the paragraph without the first line for each id (last part after the _). Then, it goes over the second file and prints the remembered lines after printing the "header". It only tests the id on the third line of each paragraph, the remaining lines are ignored. As noted above, you have not specified how to get the id. If more than the last part is important, you will have to accommodate the code slightly.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $F1,  '<', '1st_file.txt' or die $!;
my %hash1;
my $num;
while (<$F1>) {
    if (my ($id) = /^[AT]_[0-9]+_.+?_(.*)/) {
        $hash1{$id} .= $_;
    }
}

open my $F2,  '<', '2nd_file.txt' or die $!;
open my $OUT, '>', '3rd_file.txt' or die $!;
while (<$F2>) {
    if (!/_/ or /^Top_/) {
        print $OUT $_;
    } else {
        if (my ($id) = /_(.*)/) {
            print $OUT $hash1{$id} if exists $hash1{$id};
            delete $hash1{$id};
        }
    }
}
close $OUT or die $!;
```

Updated to reflect your more detailed specification:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $F1,  '<', '1st_file.txt' or die $!;
my %hash1;
my $num;
while (<$F1>) {
    if (my ($id) = /^[AT]_[0-9]+_(.*)$/) {
        $hash1{$id} .= $_;
    }
}

open my $F2,  '<', '2nd_file.txt' or die $!;
open my $OUT, '>', '3rd_file.txt' or die $!;
while (<$F2>) {
    if (!/_/ or /^Top_/) {
        print $OUT $_;
    } else {
        chomp;
        print $OUT $hash1{$_} if exists $hash1{$_};
    }
}
close $OUT or die $!;
```

Comment: Dear choroba First of all the code which you gave above is not working according to my requirement. It just gives 2nd_file.txt as output. Secondly P1_M2A always comes before P2_M2A. Let me explain again.

Comment: Firstly I want to print the first two lines of 2nd_file.txt which are like "M2A" and "Top_M2A". Think of it like Chapter Number and Chapter Name. After that the next heading in 2nd_file.txt is "P1_M2A". So at this point instead of printing P1_M2A in the output I want to print "A_153_P1_M2A" and "T_153_P1_M2A" from 1st_file.txt. After that I want to go back to 2nd_file.txt and the next line is "P2_M2A" so at this point I will come back to 1st_file.txt and I want to print "A_207_P2_M2A" and "T_207_P2_M2A" respectively.

Comment: After that there is blank line in 2nd_file.txt, after blank line another Chapter Number and Chapter Name is mentioned, which is like "T1B" and "Top_T1B" so after printing these from 2nd_file.txt I need to read the next line from 2nd_file which "P1_T1B" and now I need to go to 1st_file .txt and I want to print "A_48_P1_T1B" and "T_48_P1_T1B" respectively. Please see the output file so you can understand better.

Comment: @user1761275: I am getting exactly the expected output.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. It works fine but actually it is not. Why not. let me explain. In file "1st_file.txt" I have some text written instead of line 2 "A_153_P1_M2A"  and line 3 "T_153_P1_M2A". So if you go to "1st_file.txt" the next line after 153 is actually text such as Author of chapter and on next line is like Title of chapter. So when I try to run the original  file it does not work. It works only with the file mentioned above. So can you guide me how to fix this.

Comment: @user1761275: Please, give the full specification of the file format. Also, describe in detail how the connection from the 1st to the 2nd file should be infered. Without it, we cannot do better than just guess.

Comment: I did the modification in the "1st_file.txt".

Comment: I also did the modification in the result you can see now

Comment: Just change the regex that extracts the id: `my ($id) = /^[AT]_[0-9]+_(.*?_.*?)_/`

Comment: thanks it works fine. One more thing. If I want to remove "A_153_P1_M2A_" from the line "A_153_P1_M2A_Some text is written here" from output file what should i do. Once again thanks for your help.

Comment: @user1761275: Store only the part you want to output in the hash.

Comment: Can you please explain me how to do it.

Comment: Probably by using a regular expression. Read [perlre](http://p3rl.org/perlre) for details.

Comment: I am really confused I do not understand how to do it. Can you please guide me. I read all perlre but I am unable to get my desired result. I will be glad if you guide me.

Comment: @user1761275: Change the regex to also capture the text you want print. Store the captured text into the hash instead of the whole `$_`.